# Enabling UART on Beaglebone Black

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack, uart, beagleboard, microprocessors

I'm having trouble getting UART enabled. I've gone through many different directions on how to enable and troubleshoot from updating the uEnv.txt file to updating the kernel. I've come to conclude that it may be an issue with using a different kernel than the instructions, but I'm not sure? 
I don't know very much about the Beaglebone and I'm still learning. Whenever I try to test UART by using Python and typing the following:

> > import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
> >
> > UART.setup("UART1")

I get the error: File "stdin", line 1, in module

RuntimeError: Unable to export UART channel.

I'm also starting to worry that I simply don't have capemgr. When I run the command :

> > ls sys/devices

I don't have capemgr listed.

I'm using the latest Debian Image : Jessie Debian 8.3 (2016-01-24)

the Kernel version I'm running is 4.1.17-ti-rt-r46.

and my DTC version is 1.4.1-g1e75ebc9

I would really appreciate any help. I've been wrestling with this issue for a few days now. Thank you!

Comment: You'll have better luck opening an issue on their github repo: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO

Comment: Since your board is running the Linux operating system, you don't have direct access to any UARTs.  Check the system log to see if the serial ports have been properly probed and installed (e.g. `dmesg | grep serial`).  Check the **/dev** directory for **ttyS*** or **ttyO*** devices, i.e. serial terminals.

Comment: [http://www.thing-printer.com/cape-manager-is-back-baby/] Check this link

Answer (score 11):

Apparently the powers that be like to change files to keep us on our toes.

TamusJRoyce left a comment here: http://www.thing-printer.com/cape-manager-is-back-baby/ that helped me:

`/media/BEAGLEBONE/env.txt and /boot/uBoot/uEnv.txt has moved to /etc/default/capemgr (file which may not exist). It also has a new syntax. Add "CAPE=BB-SPI-01,BB-UART1,BB-UART2,BB-UART4" to get main ports working. Then reboot.`

To enable UART1 and UART2 on Beaglebone Black Running Debian 8

- Step 1: sudo nano /etc/default/capemgr
- Step 2: Change `#CAPE=` to: `CAPE=BB-UART1,BB-UART2`
- Step 3: reboot
- Step 4: ls /dev/ttyO*
- result: /dev/ttyO0  /dev/ttyO1  /dev/ttyO2

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was searching for hours trying to get my 4.1.17 UARTS working. No idea why none of the docs I could find mentioned the new file location for capemgr. Just a note. I had a space after the comma separating the UART ports and that caused it to fail too. No spaces!

Answer (score 2):

You can change /boot/uEnv.txt
First of all enable UARTS:

```
cape_disable=bone_capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONELT-HDMI,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
cape_enable=bone_capemgr.enable_partno=BB-UART1,BB-UART2,BB-UART4,BB-UART5
```

Then don't forget to configure pinmux with appropriate dtbo's:

```
###Overide capes with eeprom
uboot_overlay_addr0=/lib/firmware/BB-UART1-00A0.dtbo
uboot_overlay_addr1=/lib/firmware/BB-UART2-00A0.dtbo
uboot_overlay_addr2=/lib/firmware/BB-UART4-00A0.dtbo
uboot_overlay_addr3=/lib/firmware/BB-UART5-00A0.dtbo
```

Comment: why are they moving around `uEnv.txt` ?! this one was working for my distro / setup, which is a BBB wireless, `uname -a` gives me `Linux beaglebone 4.9.78-ti-r94 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 26 21:26:24 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 2):

I already answered this [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/629850/396778), but let me re-post it:

I can vouch for Debian 10 using this method:

I was able to enable all 4.5 UARTs automatically on boot-up. Unlike Debian 9 and older versions, the `uEnv.txt` is present in `/boot/`.

1. Back up this file.
2. Edit this file using `sudo` privileges:

```
$ sudo nano uEnv.txt
```

The final version for enabling all the 4.5 UARTs should look as follows:

```
#Docs: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:U-boot_partitioning_layout_2.0

uname_r=4.19.94-ti-r42
#uuid=
#dtb=

###U-Boot Overlays###
###Documentation: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#U-Boot_Overlays
###Master Enable
enable_uboot_overlays=1
# UART 1
uboot_overlay_addr0=/lib/firmware/BB-UART1-00A0.dtbo
# UART 2
uboot_overlay_addr1=/lib/firmware/BB-UART2-00A0.dtbo
# UART 4
uboot_overlay_addr2=/lib/firmware/BB-UART4-00A0.dtbo
# UART 5
uboot_overlay_addr3=/lib/firmware/BB-UART5-00A0.dtbo
# UART 3 (only TX). Note that in "uboot_overlay_addrX", the X need not be = UART id
uboot_overlay_addr4=/lib/firmware/BB-UART3-00A0.dtbo

###
###Overide capes with eeprom
#uboot_overlay_addr0=/lib/firmware/<file0>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr1=/lib/firmware/<file1>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr2=/lib/firmware/<file2>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr3=/lib/firmware/<file3>.dtbo
###
###Additional custom capes
#uboot_overlay_addr4=/lib/firmware/<file4>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr5=/lib/firmware/<file5>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr6=/lib/firmware/<file6>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr7=/lib/firmware/<file7>.dtbo
###
###Custom Cape
#dtb_overlay=/lib/firmware/<file8>.dtbo
###
###Disable auto loading of virtual capes (emmc/video/wireless/adc)
#disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_video=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_audio=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_wireless=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_adc=1
###
###PRUSS OPTIONS
###pru_rproc (4.14.x-ti kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-14-TI-00A0.dtbo
###pru_rproc (4.19.x-ti kernel)
uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-19-TI-00A0.dtbo
###pru_uio (4.14.x-ti, 4.19.x-ti & mainline/bone kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-UIO-00A0.dtbo
###
###Cape Universal Enable
enable_uboot_cape_universal=1
###
###Debug: disable uboot autoload of Cape
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr0=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr1=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr2=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr3=1
###
###U-Boot fdt tweaks... (60000 = 384KB)
#uboot_fdt_buffer=0x60000
###U-Boot Overlays###

cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 lpj=1990656 rng_core.default_quality=100 quiet

#In the event of edid real failures, uncomment this next line:
#cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 lpj=1990656 rng_core.default_quality=100 quiet video=HDMI-A-1:1024x768@60e

##enable Generic eMMC Flasher:
##make sure, these tools are installed: dosfstools rsync
#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh

#cape_enable=capemgr.enable_partno=BB-UART1,BB-UART2,BB-UART4,BB-UART5
```

3. Save and reboot. Enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the UART pins you are using are being used for other purposes. For this you need to look at the pin diagram first. If there is a conflict, you have to give up things like EMMc or hdmi and you need to make these pins possible. First disable the conflicting configurations in uEnv.txt. Then you can activate the pins as follows.

> ```
>     #! /bin/sh cd /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr File=slots if grep -q "Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,univ-emmc" "$File";  then    
>     cd
>     echo "\n Pin configuration available"
>     echo "\n UART 4 configuration p9.11 and p9.13"
>     sudo config-pin P9.11 uart
>     sudo config-pin -q P9.11
>     sudo config-pin P9.13 uart
>     sudo config-pin -q P9.13
>     echo "\n UART 1 configuration p9.26 and p9.24"
>     sudo config-pin P9.24 uart
>     sudo config-pin -q P9.24
>     sudo config-pin P9.26 uart
>     sudo config-pin -q P9.26
>     echo "\n UART 5 configuration p8.38 and p8.37"
>     sudo config-pin P8.38 uart
>     sudo config-pin -q P8.38
>     sudo config-pin P8.37 uart
>     sudo config-pin -q P8.37
>     echo "\n UART configuration end"  else    
>     echo "Oops!!configuration is not available"
>     echo "Please check uEnv.txt file and only disable HDMI" fi
> ```