# Unable to export UART channel on Beaglebone

Tags: python, debian, beagleboneblack, uart, beagleboard

I am trying to program the BeagleBone to communicate with an Arduino over UART. I have my code working flawlessly when I connect via USB, but I need to use the Adafruit BBIO library to access the UART functionality since the USB port is taken in the final design. However, when I run my code I experience the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial_commands.py", line 4, in <module>
    UART.setup("UART2")
RuntimeError: Unable to export UART channel.
```

I discovered [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881761/enabling-uart-on-beaglebone-black) indicating that i needed to update the capemngr and reboot...with no luck. I am using pins P9_21 and P9_22 for my Tx/Rx connections so I should be using UART2 for this.

Running `uname -r` I get:

`4.4.9-ti-r25`

Here are the first lines of my python code to show how this is imported:

```
from time import sleep
import serial
import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
UART.setup("UART2")

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS2', 57600)
```

What do you think I could be missing?